# heterogenous mapping, dependent types at compile time

Tags: scala, shapeless

Trying to use [this](https://gist.github.com/milessabin/aae285025a32fac0f5c1) trick, by Miles Sabin, to create a function which accepts a parameter of only a set of predefined `types`.

```
val bool =  Boolean
val timestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime())
val str = "My String"
```

and then following should pass at compile time

```
takeValue(bool)
takeValue(timestamp)
takeValue(str)
```

but

where `takeValue` should fail for `takeValue(someIntValue)` if `implicit` for `type` `Int` isn't defined.And this failure will be at compile time.

```
trait MyConv[K] { type V; def convert: AnyRef => V }

def iMakeConv[V0](con: AnyRef => V0) = new MyConv[con.type] {
  override type V = V0
  val convert = con
}

  def takeValue(value:AnyRef)(implicit conv :MyConv[value.type]) : \/[Throwable,conv.V] = \/.fromTryCatch(conv.convert(value))
```

And then

```
implicit val strAny = iMakeConv((x:Any) => x.toString)
```

Then I would want `takeValue(str)` to work at compile time but `takeValue(someIntValue)` to fail at compile time since there isn't any appropriate `implicit` defined for it. Basically want to limit(at compile time) type of `types` `takeValue` can take and fail for others.

Certainly I am doing something wrong here because when calling

```
takeValue("string")
```

it throws following at compile time

```
 could not find implicit value for parameter conv: 
 MyConv[String("string")]
- not enough arguments for method takeValue: (implicit conv: 
 MyConv[String("string")])scalaz.\/[Throwable,conv.V]. 
 Unspecified value parameter conv.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The meaning of `.type` is often misunderstood. The type `value.type` is a type with only a single value - `value`. Even if `value` is known to be `String`, `value.type` is not `String`, but specifically only one `String` - `value`.

As a result, the code tries to find a `MyConv[value.type]`, of which none exist, even if there is a `MyConv[String]` available.

Have `takeValue` use a type parameter instead:

```
def takeValue[T](value: T)(implicit conv: MyConv[T]) : \/[Throwable, conv.V] = \/.fromTryCatch(conv.convert(value))
```

Or alternatively make the type parameter of `MyConv`  contravariant:

```
trait MyConv[-K] { type V; def convert: AnyRef => V }
```

Which would allow a `MyConv[T]` to be used if `value.type` is a subtype of `T`.

You also need a different `MyConv` and `iMakeConv`:

```
trait MyConv[K] { type V; def convert: K => V }

def iMakeConv[K, V0](con: K => V0) = new MyConv[K] {
  override type V = V0
  val convert = con
}
```

Comment: I would probably steer clear of using variance in cases like this, but otherwise, +1.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner :great answer. shouldn't this `implicit` work? `  implicit val strConv = iMakeConv[Any,String] ((x: Any) => x.toString)` ?

Comment: @VikasPandya That implicit looks fine to me.